# how to check csv file format , its taking other files format also i tried with this code

Tags: php

```
<div class="form-group">
    Please, only use this file format to upload employee details : <a href="uploads/csv_format/New_members.csv">Download Here</a>
    <hr>
    <input type="file"  name="file"  id="browes"/>       
</div>
```

```
if(isset($_POST['upload_empl']))    {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
                "Error Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
                echo "<script>alert('choose correct file format');window.location='upload-students.php';</script>";
            }
            else{
                $mimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv');
                if (in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$mimes)){ 
   code goes here
}
  else
{
   echo "<script>alert('choose correct file format');window.location='upload-students.php';</script>";
 }
```

Comment: The code is not complete and it is hard to read while is not formated. Please update this question and put there the whole code.

Comment: Well, you do allow several mime types, not just csv...

Comment: Pls also share the full code and describe the issue in a more detailed manner.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: hi i am new to stack flow please suggest tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SplFileInfo::getExtension()` method to check the file format.

See for reference, http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getextension.php